# Including citation and references when using appendix on RMarkdown

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

I am working on `RMarkdown` to generate a report that includes an appendix after references. I have written the appendix on a different `RMarkdown` file and adapted my principal file to compile it. This is the code for my principal Rmd file that generates report:

````
---
bibliography: bb.bib
fontsize: 11pt
nocite: '@*'
output: 
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      after_body: Demo2.Rmd
      keep_tex: yes
link-citations: true
---
\newpage

\section{Testing}\label{sec1}
```{r}
summary(cars)
```
\section{Demo}
This was done using @shiina and we will use some info from Section \ref{sec1} to do.
```{r}
summary(iris[,1:2])
```
\section{References}
````

The file `bb.bib` contains next references:

```
@article {shiina,
author = {Shiina, Takayuki and Birge, John R.},
title = {Stochastic unit commitment problem},
journal = {International Transactions in Operational Research},
volume = {11},
number = {1},
publisher = {Blackwell Publishing},
pages = {19--32},
year = {2004},
}

@book{groewe2001,
  title={Stochastic unit commitment in hydro-thermal power production planning},
  author={Gr{\"o}we-Kuska, N. and R{\"o}misch, W.},
  year={2001},
  series = { Preprints aus dem Institut f{\"u}r Mathematik },
  publisher = { Humboldt-Universit{\"a}t zu Berlin, Institut f{\"u}r Mathematik },
}
```

Finally, my appendix Rmd file, `Demo2.Rmd`, contains this structure:

```
\appendix
\section*{Appendix}
\section{Additional info}
In this section we also follow @shiina to explain concepts.
```

Compilation works fine and generate document but issues are appearing in the appendix section. I used a reference with `@shiina` to cite something, but I am getting this output in the final report:
[image]

The circle in black shows that citation from bibliography is not working. Instead of `@shiina`, it should appear `Shiina and Birge (2004)`. I have tried replacing Rmd file with a TeX file but it did not work.

Is it any way to correct that?, I do not know if `after_body` needs to be adjusted or what to do.

Comment: This site might hep you.
https://www.r-bloggers.com/bibliography-with-knitr-cite-your-references-and-packages/

Comment: @JKJ That reference doesn't say anything about references in the appendix. The post could probably be slightly more clear about this, but the issue is that references work fine in the main body of the document, but aren't handled correctly in the appendix.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but did you add your bibliography to your appendix-header?
To make sure that the reference appears in your reference-list, you might also want to add the appendix-references as ``nocite`` items (like explained [on this page](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html))

Comment: @JKJ yes, what you said is true. I am new in Rmarkdown and I do not know how to manage that issue.

Comment: @MaxTeflon Thanks for replying. I do not how to add that in my second Rmd file. I hve tried but I got text and it does not work. I am new in Rmarkdown.

Comment: @MaxTeflon could you please help me with an example of how to do this. I have tried what you recommended but still I get same text without proper citation. Thx!

Comment: I tried it, it was a sub-optimal idea ^^.
But I am trying to find a slightly hackey solution, allthough I'm not sure whether it will work.

Comment: @MaxTeflon Many thanks for your help ! I will accept your answer because of your appreciated help!

Comment: Don't mention it, I enjoyed the challenge. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I did actually find a solution that does use some minor trickery.

````
---
bibliography: bb.bib
fontsize: 11pt
nocite: '@*'
output:
  pdf_document:
      keep_tex: true
      includes:
        after_body: Demo2.tex
link-citations: true
---

```{r,include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
rmarkdown::render('Demo2.Rmd')
a <- readChar('Demo2.tex', file.size('Demo2.tex'))
a <- a %>% str_remove('[[:space:]]*\\\\hypertarget[[\\w\\W]]+\\z') %>%
  str_remove('\\A[[\\w\\W]]+begin.document.')
writeChar(a, 'Demo2.tex',eos = NULL)
```


\newpage

\section{Testing}\label{sec1}
```{r}
summary(cars)
```

\section{Demo}
This was done using @shiina and we will use some info from Section \ref{sec1} to do.
```{r}
summary(iris[,1:2])
```
\section{References}
````

---

And your Appendix-file:

```
---
bibliography: bb.bib
fontsize: 11pt
output:
  pdf_document:
      keep_tex: yes
link-citations: true
---


\appendix
\section*{Appendix}
\section{Additional info}
In this section we also follow @shiina to explain concepts.

# References
```

---

results in:

[image]

---

The way it works is to render the `Demo2.Rmd`- file before rendering the actual file and to keep the associated `.tex`- file.
Then the non included R-chunk cuts of all the parts we don't want to have at the end of the main file and overwrites the `Demo2.tex`-file.
What remains is the exact `tex`-code you need to have your references working.

Feels pretty dirty, but should work.